# C# - Azure SSO token expiring throwing error

Tags: c#, azure, web-applications, single-sign-on

I am attempting to write a c# web app that uses Azure for a SSO provider.

I am using Owin as the middle layer.

```
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                    // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                    // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                    // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
                    // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false // Simplification (see note below)
                    },
                    // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                    }
                });
        }
```

So it logs in fine, but after **1 hour** when i attempt to do AJAX requests (regardless of whether the page has refreshed) i am getting a CORS error because the token has expired.

How do i 'keep it alive' the token so that users don't have 1 hour to complete their work?

Answer (score 1):

A token lifetime policy is a type of policy object that contains token lifetime rules. Use the properties of the policy to control specified token lifetimes. **If no policy is set, the system enforces the default lifetime value.**

You can **set access token lifetime to one day** so that you will not expired with one hour limit.

[image]

You can set the token lifetime configuration on your Service Principal, Application, or Tenant.

You'll need to use Powershell to create a policy describing the behavior you want, and link it to your service principal, tenant, or application. Keep in mind, if you're building a multi-tenant app, the owner of the tenant can overwrite your policy.

**Note**: Don't rely on the token lifetime in your app as it can change at any time.

You can set these properties using [Azure AD Powershell Commands](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.2.102). Then run the following commands to set an access token lifetime:

1.Sign in to Powershell.

```
Connect-AzureAD -Confirm
```

2.Create a new policy to set the Access Token lifetime to 2 hours. You can change this to be between 10 minutes and 1 day.

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"24:00:00","MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"02:00:00"}}') -DisplayName "WebPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

3.Get the policy's ObjectId.

```
Get-AzureAdPolicy
```

4.Link the new policy to your application. You can get the objectId of your app using the [GraphExplorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

```
Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy -Id <ObjectId of the Application> -RefObjectId <ObjectId of the Policy>
```

For more details, you could refer to this article about [Azure AD Configurable Token Lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-types).

Comment: Don't forget, you could always use the 'refresh-token' to refresh the access-token.